# mainAxisAlignment not working to align iconButton to the top

Tags: flutter, dart

As you can see from the photo I have a Row with 3 columns.

|iconButton|column 2 textfields|iconButton|

I cannot get the iconButtons to align correctly. I want the arrow button to align to the top of its respective column. I want the + button to be at the bottom the respective column.

[image: photo]

```
 _scaffoldKey.currentState
    .showBottomSheet((context) {
      return new Container(
        height: 400.0,
        color: Colors.white,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, right: 2),
        child: new Center(
          // child: new Text('Persistent Bottom Sheet'),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                          color: Colors.black,
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                              height: 35,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 45, left: 0, right: 20),
                              child: AutoCompleteTextView(
                                suggestionsApiFetchDelay: 300,
                                focusGained: () {},
                                onTapCallback: (_) async {

                                },
                                focusLost: () {

                                },
                                onValueChanged: (String text) {

                                },
                                controller: startEditingController,
                                suggestionStyle:
                                    Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
                                getSuggestionsMethod:
                                    getLocationSuggestionsList,
                                tfTextAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                tfStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  color: Theme.of(context)
                                      .textTheme
                                      .bodyText2
                                      .color,
                                ),
                                tfTextDecoration: InputDecoration(
                                  contentPadding:
                                      EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 8.0),
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.grey[800],
                                        width: 1.0),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.deepPurple[600],
                                        width: 1.0),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                                  ),
                                  hintText: "Current Location",
                                  labelText: 'Start',
                                  labelStyle: kcarPurpleLabelStyle,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 35,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 5, left: 0, right: 0),
                              child: AutoCompleteTextView(
                                suggestionsApiFetchDelay: 300,
                                focusGained: () {},
                                onTapCallback: (_) async {

                                },
                                focusLost: () {

                                },
                                onValueChanged: (String text) {

                                },
                                controller: startEditingController,
                                suggestionStyle:
                                    Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
                                getSuggestionsMethod:
                                    getLocationSuggestionsList,
                                tfTextAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                tfStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  color: Theme.of(context)
                                      .textTheme
                                      .bodyText2
                                      .color,
                                ),
                                tfTextDecoration: InputDecoration(
                                  contentPadding:
                                      EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 8.0),
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.grey[800],
                                        width: 1.0),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.deepPurple[600],
                                        width: 1.0),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                                  ),
                                  hintText: "Current Location",
                                  labelText: 'Destination',
                                  labelStyle: kcarPurpleLabelStyle,
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ]),
                    ),
                     Column(
                       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                       mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                       children: [
                         Stack(alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft, children: [
                           IconButton(
                             icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                             color: Colors.black,
                             onPressed: () {},
                           ),
                         ]),
                       ],
                     ),
                  ]),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Comment: Is this issue fixed?

Comment: No it is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by making use of your Row and column widgets mainAxisAlignment property.

One approach is shown below. Give some height to the row or make it expanded.

```
return Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                            color: Colors.black,
                            onPressed: () {},
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                  height: 35,
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: 45, left: 0, right: 20),
                                  child: TextField(),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height: 35,
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: 5, left: 0, right: 0),
                                  child: TextField(),
                                )
                              ]),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                              color: Colors.black,
                              iconSize: 12,
                              onPressed: () {},
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Comment: Not working. Now both the icons are at the top. So the arrow is center top where it should be, but the + is now also at the top center.

Comment: Did you used the same code `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end`, this for plus should do the trick. Or check on your parent widget's for any overrides to this call

Comment: I did. Nothing makes move to the bottom. I have updated the question with the entire code. What I am after is identical to the Uber app when you click on the set destination field.

Comment: The IconButton has a default padding, could that be what is casuing the issue @jdog

Comment: Not the default padding its only 8. In the photo that is the blue.

Comment: I updated the answer. Can u check this one. For visualizing what or where went unexpected, I added some containers with color. You can use this technique as a beginner for identifying the failure points.

Comment: The `Expanded(child: Row(` will tell the row to take all the available size of its parent

Comment: @krishnakumarcn if you make answer I can give you credit.

Comment: I'm not here for credits. You can check the updated answer I provided here which I verified using my time. If this is not solving your issue or you need something different, read some documentation on flutter layouting. Thanks.